Cracks in 1940s basement stairwell
I bought my house in 2021, original construction was in 1948. I noticed these cracks in the stairwell to the basement and on the wall directly to the right at the bottom of the stairs, just wondering if this is something be concerned about. There are no other cracks that I can see anywhere else in the house. My main concern is less the long hairline one, and more the one at the corner and the horizontal ones across the lower part of the ceiling.
I had a structural engineer come out a year ago to look at some other things in the room next to the stairwell, he concluded that the ceiling supports were fine, so I’m wondering if this is something to do with the foundation or simply cosmetic. Trying to decide if I need to call him back to come look at this or if this is something I can fix myself. Thanks!
Photos: https://imgur.com/a/R0eFbBk


Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works. Then, give the site search a go and see if any of the many similar questions help you out.

That's a very trivial surface crack to get all excited about.
If you repaired it last week and it cracked this week, that might be concerning.
Otherwise, repair it this week and call the engineer if it cracks again next week.
